# Find area of circle without sector but with triangle: Do not use trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, mathematical-modeling, angle

How to do this without using trigonometry please?

> A sheep is tethered to a post which is 6 m from a long fence. The length of rope is 9 m. Find the area which the sheep can feed on.

[image]

Let the post be $(0,0)$. Define such area to be $A_f$ then $A_f = A_c - A_s + A_t$ where:

$A_c$ is the area of the circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $r=9$

$A_s$ is the area of the sector with arc with endpoints $(-x,6)$ and $(x,6)$ having angle $\theta$

$A_t$ is the area of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(-x,6)$ and $(x,6)$

where $x$ is the positive number on the circle whose $y$-coordinate is $6$.

I got $x$, $A_c$ and $A_t$. How do we get $A_s$?

What I would do is

> $A_s = \frac12 (\theta) (81m^2)$ where $\theta$ is obtained by
>
> $\cos ( \frac{\theta}{2} ) = \frac69$

This is from IB Standard Level. Students know degree radian conversion, arc length $l = r \theta$, area of sector $\frac12 (\theta) (r^2)$, quadratics, functions, exponentials, logarithms, functions, sequences and series.

Students don't yet know $\sin$, $\cos$, trig stuff.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to determine the angle $\theta$ without trig.

Comment: the IB assumes some prior knowledge. Even if the chapter on trig functions isn't covered yet, they should know how to do some basic trig from pre-IB math

Comment: @NickPavlov LOL THANKS.

Comment: @grand_chat right thanks!

Comment: Do these students know integration ?